# Could IMAP authentication be adapted to support 2FA?

Tags: multi-factor, imap

Theoretically? (If no, why? And if yes, why hasn't it been done?)

Comment: How would this work ?  Every time my mail client goes to check for new mail, I have to enter a OTP?

Comment: @mti2935: IMAP typically keeps the connection open and even gets informed if there are new mails (i.e. push instead of pull). Also, similar to how web based applications don't require a full login all the time but instead maintain a session this could be done within IMAP too.

Comment: Does this answer you? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/173807/does-imap-pop3-asp-undermine-two-factor-auth

Answer (score 2):

> Could IMAP authentication be adapted to support 2FA?

IMAP can support multiple authentication methods, i.e. the protocol is extensible.

> ...  why hasn't it been done

It has been done. Modern clients like Thunderbird support XOAUTH2 which basically uses a web client with OAuth2 which then can do all the normal things OAuth2 can do including 2FA.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my naivety is confusing me: on one hand you're saying that it has been done, but on the other you immediately mention the client side. I am wondering about server-side 2FA support for IMAP. Could you provide any relevant links?

Comment: @user664833: Google and probably others support 2FA with IMAP using the XAUTH2 authentication method - so there is obviously support on the server side at least with some server implementations. But I  focused on the client side since there is where the login credentials must be provided. See [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) for a description of how XAUTH2 works.