# Genuine security of IMAP vs Exchange Active Sync mail access

Tags: exchange, imap

I agree that - as always - having two protocols available potentially offers a greater attack surface than either of them. I know Active Sync allows to enforce organisational admin capabilities to wipe mobile devices, which *may* help for security.

But beyond that: is there a **genuine, inheritent security drawback of IMAP as compared to Exchange Active Sync (given both are configured according to best practice)?** In other words: given an up-to-date on premise Exchange server set to best practice configuration, **does it make sense from a security point of view to disable IMAP and allow only Active Sync?**

This may or may not include aspects such as

- Even if equally secure per se, can either protocol better prevent users to misconfigure their device (i.e. reduced security problem on client, not server side)? AFAIK webserver can restrict communication to secure protocols to prevent user to select insufficient encryption also on IMAP - correct?
- Are additional security features available only for Exchange Active Sync but not IMAP (e.g. 2FA, additional certificates etc)? (at least 2FA does not seem the problem, as discussed in [Does IMAP/POP3/ASP undermine Two-Factor Auth?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/173807/142421))
- Are there more, less actively fixed, or unfixed/unfixable inheritent design problems with IMAP but not Exchange Active Sync?
- Anything else to consider?

Use case is mail from academic organisation both for workplace and private devices including PC and mobile phones. The mail server runs Exchange, which can be used via Active Sync or IMAP. The question about IMAP is both on IMAP implementation using an Exchange server, and the IMAP protocol in general irrespective of a specific software.

I am grateful to fantastic Q/A on IMAP and Exchange Active Sync  topics here and elsewhere - I could learn a lot, but not find an answer to my question.

I am aware of differences in functionality, i.e. that Exchange Active Sync can manage not only mail, but also calendar etc., but this is not my question.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks - will clarify!

Comment: Does the used Exchange server support oAuth authentication via IMAP? Not having to store the account password in the mail client but instead using an oAuth token which can be replaced/invalidated at any time is IMHO a big security improvement. I think for Active Sync this feature is supported a way longer.

Comment: @Robert  Thanks for the hint, I would have to ask, but - please correct me - I suppose there is no general reason why this should not be possible to implement. If oAuth is best practice (and practically usable, I have not used it myself), I would see this as "... configured according to best practice", what we'd like to look at.

Comment: "should not be possible to implement" you are talking about a closed source software so possible is everything but depending on the used Exchange version (on-premise? which version, or MS 365 in the cloud?) you have to use what is available.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, added "on premise" (does this make a difference? please comment) and clarified my question. "not possible to implement": didn't mean to change software, but rather enable oAuth - I believe this is possible from what I read and according to your previous comment, but may be wrong, please correct me if so!

Comment: I am not an Exchange expert but as there are three on-premise versions of Exchange (2013, 2016 and 2019). So there might be a difference between the versions and their supported security or authentication technology.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140751/discussion-between-martin-and-robert).